# Kernel function: lock_timer_base(struct timer_list *, unsigned long *)

Tags: timer, linux-kernel, delay, scheduler

I'm trying to understand,

```
__mod_timer(struct timer_list *timer, unsigned long expires,
                                                bool pending_only, int pinned)
```

this's calling `lock_timer_base` method. I'm not sure, what exactly its trying to do? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trying to reschedule a timer.
`timer` points to a timer object, which may be set to expire some time in the future.
This function wants to change it, so it would expire at another time (`expires`).

The lock is needed to make sure data doesn't get corrupt.
For example, it's possible that the old expiration time is just now, and another CPU is handling the same timer at the same time. The lock is there to make sure things still work.

Comment: Thanks ugoren, any idea for Linux user space Timers (setting up timer without simultaneously blocking the calling process). From what I knw there are jst 2 sys calls: timer_settime, Alarm.

Comment: In user space, timers are not so popular. They pop up whenever they want, making your code kind of multi-threaded. It's better to occasionally check the time and do what you want. If you use `select`/`poll`/`epoll`, you can tell them when to wake up.